# Experience precautionary messages from ... - is experience the right word here?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

Consider the following sentence:

> Undergoing historical studies allows students to recall the ancient events and experience precautionary messages from them

What I mean by "experience precautionary messages" is to learn from the mistakes which were committed by people in the past. Is the usage of the word "experience" correct here? What word is more appropriate than "experience" in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Undergoing historical studies allows students to recall the ancient events and **comprehend their** precautionary messages".

[To comprehend](https://www.lexico.com/definition/comprehend)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've been a great help